# Load non-Java resource from WAR

Tags: web-applications, jboss, classloader, java

I'm trying to load a non-Java resource from a particular WAR file. This is how I'm trying to achieve this:

```
SomeClassInMyWarFile.class.getClassLoader().getResource("path/file.txt");
```

Works perfectly when running in JBoss 4 - where getClassLoader() returns an instance of `WebAppClassLoader`.

But when I try to run this code under JBoss 6, I get an instance of `BaseClassLoader`, which in return isn't able to locate the resource inside of that WAR.

For debugging purposes, when I call getResource("./") on both, these are the results:

- JBoss 4

  ```
  "file:/C:/path/to/my/WarFile.war/"
  ```
- JBoss 6

  ```
  "file:/C:/jboss6/bin/a1k2347-kpm5pr-hjfoi81u-1-hjfoj582-dz/"
  ```

  "/a1k2347-kpm5pr-hjfoi81u-1-hjfoj582-dz/" doesn't even exist.

I have the feeling that I didn't set up my jboss6 correctly, or that I'm missing another crucial thing here..
Any ideas what could be happening? Or maybe even someone who is able to explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, seems like I've been missing some basic understanding of how WAR files are supposed to work.

After I understood that only `WEB-INF/classes` and `WEB-INF/lib` are added to the classloader's classpath, and **NOT** the root directory of the WAR file, solving the problem was pretty simple:

As a quick fix, I changed `path/file.txt` to `../../path/file.txt`, so the path to the resource is relative to `WEB-INF/classes`

This is ugly, indeed. Someday, I will invest some time in enhancing our build procedure, so the resources automatically get moved into a directory that is on the classpath.